# How to move specialized template function into cpp?

Tags: c++, templates

```
class UString {
public:
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_same<T, bool>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    T To() const;
    template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, bool>::value>::type* = nullptr>
    bool To() const;
};


template<typename T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<T, bool>::value>::type*>
bool UString::To() const {
    // ...
}
```

Can I move `bool To() const` into cpp file?

Comment: If you move it to a cpp file, the specialization will only apply in that cpp file.

Comment: @DrewDormann The function has nothing to do with the template type. So I thought there should be a way to just put it in a cpp.

Comment: Why is there a SFINAE condition? Can't you specialize the function?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes I should.

Comment: Then moving it to the .cpp file should work.